# NSWindow + titlebar without rounded corners?

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, cocoa

Is it possible to have a NSWindow that still has a title bar but doesn't have rounded corners?

Ideally i would be able to do the following:

```
self.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true;
self.titleVisibility = NSWindowTitleVisibility.Hidden;
```

Leaving me with almost full control of my window rendering but still able to piggy back off of the default window control buttons.

I tried many combinations but it seems when the `NSTitledWindowMask` mask is present the window automatically starts rounding its corners.

Comment: Why don't you customize a borderless window for your needs?

Comment: Because if i do that i need to create the close, minimize, and maximize buttons, and to my knowledge theres not a nice way to do this.

Comment: This seems impossible at the moment so i opened up an issue in relation to manually creating the buttons/controls http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32503282/nswindowbutton-nswindow-standardwindowbutton-button-not-highlighting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get this working for the life of me so my solution was to write my own custom buttons. This works fine for me because my `NSWindow` is already custom so there wont be a clash of style.

https://gist.github.com/icodeforlove/a334884e59784b4c2567